# Batch image resizing

Tags: image-processing, batch

Does anyone know of a tool that can resize a batch of images to the largest size that keeps each one under a specified file size (preserving aspect ratio)?  This would be very useful when uploading to sites with different file size limits

Edit: only needs to run on Windows

Comment: See: [can i reduce image file size in photoshop to under a specific size?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/can-i-reduce-image-file-size-in-photoshop-to-under-a-specific-size)

Comment: At the very least, you need to [edit] to specify the system that you want this software to run on. Windows, OSX, iOS, Android, GNU/Linux, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use IrfanView for batch resizing. It is a free program and has many powerful tools including the ability to batch file resize by file size, megapixel size, or Both.

http://www.irfanview.com/

Here are two screen captures of the batch file page.

Under "Advanced" you can set Width and Height or MegaPixel size.

[image]

Under "Options" you can set a file size limit.  "Set file size: 65 KB".

[image]

Comment: It is a good answer. Probably some people is voting down for the dependency on the image. Try to add the descriptive text Mike.